# Incorrect syntax near ')'. Dim temp As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString())

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Source of the error:

```vb
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(checkuser, con)
Dim temp As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString())
con.Close()
```

Full code:

```vb
Protected Sub Buttonlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Buttonlogin.Click
    If (Page.IsPostBack) Then

        Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DMS;User ID=sa;Password=football2u")

        con.Open()
        Dim checkuser As String = "Select count from DMSRegform where Username ='" + TextBoxuser.Text + "')"
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(checkuser, con)

        Dim temp As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString())
        con.Close()

        If temp = 1 Then
            con.Open()
            Dim checkpasswordquery As String = "Select password from DMSRegform Where Username ='" + TextBoxpass.Text + "')"
            Dim Passwordcmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(checkpasswordquery, con)
            Dim password As String = Passwordcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()

            If password = TextBoxpass.Text Then
                'Session["New"] = Textboxuser.text
                Response.Write("Password correct")
            Else
                Response.Write("Password is incorrect")
            End If
        Else
            Response.Write("Username is incorrect")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How about removing .ToString()?

Comment: Now that you've showed the error,what about the code? See [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Please show the text of the variable _checkuser_

Comment: At least tell us on which line the error is

Comment: As @Steve already said, the problem is almost surely in the sql query in `checkuser`

Comment: Go step by step. Run your query in ssms first to make sure it result what you expect. (Here itself you ll catch this error). Then put the query in your command.

Comment: The error is on line 28

Comment: @muffi didnt work

Comment: Also if you are after the count of records you must specify a column name. * works fine also. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE`. Otherwise the select statement will expect the column name `count` to exist which I'm guessing is not what you want. Maybe it is, in which case my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Dim checkuser As String = "Select count from DMSRegform where Username ='" + TextBoxuser.Text + "')"
....
Dim checkpasswordquery As String = "Select password from DMSRegform Where Username ='" + TextBoxpass.Text + "')"
```

Why are you adding a final `)` to your queries? Remove the `)` in both of them and it should go fine.

Also never use string concatenation to compose your queries. Use parametrized queries, or you'll be exposed to Sql Injection.

Comment: As was mentioned in this comment, PLEASE do yourself a favor and look into parameterizing queries.  This is wide open to abuse, including but not limited to credentials being used inappropriately or tables being outright dropped when they're not supposed to be.

Answer (score 2):

You have a closing bracket `)` on the end of your query, but no matching opening bracket. Just remove it.

Also your code is vulnerable to [**SQL Injection**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). What if someone decides to enter:

```sql
'; DROP TABLE DMSRegform; --
```

in `TextBoxuser`?

You most certainly should switch to a [**parameterized query**](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) in order to avoid this being a security issue:

```vb
Dim checkuser As String = "Select count from DMSRegform where Username = @User"

Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(checkuser, con)

cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar, <maximum column length>).Value = TextBoxuser.Text
```